# Getting error while trying to save and apply existing machine learning model to new dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am trying to use this model https://github.com/aninda052/Disasters-on-social-media-NLP/blob/master/Disasters%20on%20social%20media.ipynb
, I searched for a way to save this model and use it with new dataset in other application an I find out use pickle, and I add this to code like this

```
import pickle
model_tfidf=LogisticRegression( C=30.0,class_weight='balanced', solver='newton-cg', 
                         multi_class='multinomial', n_jobs=-1, random_state=5)
model_tfidf.fit(x_train_tfidf, y_train)
predicted_tfidf=model_tfidf.predict(x_test_tfidf)
Pkl_Filename = "Pickle_RL_Model.pkl"  

with open(Pkl_Filename, 'wb') as file:  
    pickle.dump(model_tfidf, file)
```

after that I tried to create new project to load and use this model and the code is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd
import pickle
with open('Pickle_RL_Model.pkl', 'rb') as file:  
    Pickled_LR_Model = pickle.load(file)
x=["hi disaster","flood disaster","cry sad bad ","srong storm"]

tfd=TfidfVectorizer()
new_data_vec=tfd.fit_transform(x)
Ypredict = Pickled_LR_Model.predict(new_data_vec)
```

but I got error said:

```
X has 8 features per sample; expecting 16988
```

I don't know what I did wrong, any help please.

Comment: Seems the datasets have different number of features, machine learning models take fixed size features, so this won't work.

Comment: So what can I do in order to use this model

Comment: You need to use it with datasets that have the same number of features than the training set, why does your new dataset have a different number of features?

Comment: Okay I'm a bit confused right now, what do you mean exactly by saying different number of features? excuse my question I am very new to machine learning field and I am trying to learn